# Custom Json Response using Active model serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting a response from using a custom serializers like:

```
render json: @required_user, :serializer => CustomuserSerializer
```

I want a Json somthing like this:

```
render json: { status: 'Success', message: "User Created Successfully", data: @required_user, :serializer => CustomuserSerializer }
```

How can i achieve this? Searched over on stackoverflow to find solutions that are not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a common method for success like below and this can be used in all places.

```
    def render_success_response(data: nil, message: nil, serializer_options: {})
      resp_data = { status: 'success' }
      resp_data[:message] = message if message
    
      # Serialize the resource
      resp_data[:data] = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(data, serializer_options)if data
    
      render json: resp_data, status: 200
    end
```

- **data** is the active record relation or active record object to be serialized. In your case - `@required_user`
- **message** - Success message to be sent in the response. in here - "User Created Successfully"
- **serializer_options** - serialization options needed. Like `serializer, each_serializer, include` and other options.